# My clients changed dashboard access after working

Tags: php, wordpress, web, phpmyadmin

Hello i have worked with a client in project.This was building a WordPress website.But when my worked 95% done.***Then the clients changed the wordpress dashboard access***.And not contacting with me.Not receiving my calls also.
**But i have database USER PASSWORD.**
So anyway to login to the dashboard by database access?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database you can reset the password from there. Just run the following query in your database:

```
UPDATE `wp_users` 
SET `user_pass` = MD5( 'New Password' ) 
WHERE `wp_users`.`user_login` = "Username of the account";
```